# Routing to a secondary IP address on the same network interface

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I am adding a secondary ip address to my eth0 NIC so that I can experiment with making the machine a router.

On the router, `ip addr show eth0` gives me:

```
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0a:35:00:0e:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.0.39/24 brd 10.10.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.1/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20a:35ff:fe00:e57/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

the route table looks like this:

```
default via 10.10.0.1 dev eth0 
10.10.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.0.39 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
```

When I try to ping 192.168.1.2 from the router, the host is unreachable.  I am not sure why?

I can ping the router from 192.168.1.2.

Comment: Which of the router's IP addresses can you ping from 192.168.1.2? And did you do any troubleshooting? (Does an ARP request go out? Do you get an ARP reply? Does the ping go out? Etctetera)

Comment: I can ping the router (192.168.1.1) from 192.168.1.2, but not the other way around.  From the router I can ping systems on the 10.10.0.0 subnet but not on the 192.168.1.0 subnet.

Comment: Information that I did not think mattered at the time seems to make a difference: The machine with the address 192.168.1.2 is a Windows machine.  When I repeat the experiment with Linux hosts in all locations I can ping both of the devices (one on the 192.168.1 subnet, and the other on the 10.10.0 subnet) from the router.  I am still not sure why that is the case, but I am going to leave it for now.